# QComboBox: the addItem function trigger index change signal

Tags: qt, qcombobox

I am using `QComboBox` in my project. And I find that the `addItem` function would trigger `currentIndexChanged` signal.

The minimum code to reproduce this problem is:

```
class Test: public QWidget
{
public:
  QComboBox * m_box;
  Test()
  {
    m_box = new QComboBox;
    connect(m_box, static_cast<void (QComboBox::*)(int)>(&QComboBox::currentIndexChanged), this, &Test::IndexChangeSlot);
    m_box->addItem("test");
  }
public slots:
  void IndexChangeSlot(int index)
  {
    std::cout<<"index changed"<<std::endl;
  }
}
```

Why `addItem` would trigger `currentIndexChanged` signal?
How can I avoid this signal caused by `addItem`?

Answer (score 0):

CurrentIndex was -1 (nothing is selected) and become 0.
To avoid disconnect before adding items and connect back, or use variable to ignore signal temporary, or connect after initialisation.